# equations of lines using vectors with no coordinate system

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have some nonzero vector $\vec{n}$. I want to find the locus of points satisfying $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{r}=0$ where $\vec{r}$ is position vector.

we know $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{r} = | \vec{n} | | Pr_{ \vec{n} } \vec{r} | = 0 $

Here I dont know how to proceed. I know how to do it with coordinates (So much easier!). But, how can we find the locus without using coordinate system?

Comment: Maybe you should explain your notation: What is $Pr_{\vec n}\vec r$? Moreover, in my opinion, $\{\vec r,\vec r\cdot\vec n=0\}$ is a valid description for what you want already. Or do you want another "description"? What you are looking at is a codimension one hyperplane. and there are various ways of writing such an object down.

Comment: Projection of $r$ onto $n$ and we are in da plane

Comment: Ok, but according to what you said, $Pr_{\vec n}\vec r=0$ and you still need to specify what you mean by "the locus of points satisfying…". One possible (coordinate-free) description of that locus is e.g. $\vec n^\perp$. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

We assume that the ambient space has finite dimension (thus can be assimilated to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R^p}$, but we don't need it).

The only coordinate-free argument is to say that you are looking for the **kernel** of the following linear "form" from $\mathbb{R^p}$ to $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\vec r \rightarrow \vec r.\vec n$$

which is naturally a vector subspace whose dimension (using rank-nullity theorem) is $p-1$, thus an hyperplane. This kind of maximal proper subspace is called an hyperplane, denoted here by $\vec n^\perp$ as @frog said (the orthogonal subspace to $\mathbb{R^p}$)